# Project Euler #14 in Swift - Longest Collatz sequence

Tags: programming-challenge, swift, collatz-sequence

I just finished [Project Euler #14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14) in Swift, and since there is not any version yet on Code Review, I would like to have some comments on what I did to try to improve it.

> The following iterative sequence is defined for the set of positive
>   integers:
>
> n → n/2 (n is even)
>
> n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)
>
> Using the rule above and starting with 13, we generate the following
>   sequence:
>
> 13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1
>
> It can be seen that this
>   sequence (starting at 13 and finishing at 1) contains 10 terms.
>   Although it has not been proved yet (Collatz Problem), it is thought
>   that all starting numbers finish at 1.
>
> Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?
>
> NOTE: Once the chain starts the terms are allowed to go above one
>   million.

```
import Foundation

func collatzSequenceForNumber(var number:Int, inout steps:[Int]) -> Int {

    var numberOfSteps = 0
    var found = false
    let initialNumber = number

    while (found == false) {

        if number % 2 == 0 {
            number /= 2
        } else {
            number = (number * 3 + 1) / 2
            numberOfSteps++
        }

        found = number < steps.count ? steps[number] > 0 : false
        numberOfSteps++
    }

    numberOfSteps += steps[number]
    steps[initialNumber] = numberOfSteps

    return numberOfSteps
}

func longestCollatzSequence(maxNumber:Int) -> (Int, Int) {
    var collatzSequence = (number:0, steps:0)
    var steps:[Int] = [Int](count: maxNumber, repeatedValue: 0)
    steps[1] = 1

    for var number = 2; number < maxNumber; number++ {

        let steps = collatzSequenceForNumber(number, &steps)
        if steps > collatzSequence.steps {
            collatzSequence = (number, steps)
        }
    }

    return collatzSequence
}

func euler14() {

    let result:(number:Int, steps:Int) = longestCollatzSequence(999_999)

    println(result.number)
}

func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(operation:() -> ()) {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    operation()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    println("Time elapsed : \(timeElapsed) s")
}

printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(euler14)
```

The code executes in 0.07s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collatzSequenceForNumber()` returns the *length* of the Collatz sequence and not a sequence itself, so a better name might be `collatzLength()`:

```
func collatzLength(var number:Int, inout steps:[Int]) -> Int {
    var numberOfSteps = 0
    let initialNumber = number
    // ...
}
```

The `steps`
parameter is an array used as cache. But in `longestCollatzSequence()`, the same name `steps` is used for both the caching array and the computed number of steps.
For more consistence, I would suggest to use `steps` for the number of steps
only and a different name `cache` for the caching array:

```
func collatzLength(var number:Int, inout cache:[Int]) -> Int {
    var steps = 0
    let initialNumber = number
    // ...
    return steps
}
```

The `number` parameter is declared as a variable
and modified in the function. That is fine generally, but here you need the original value of the parameter at the end of the function. It might be
clearer to treat the  parameter as constant and modify a local copy:

```
func collatzLength(number:Int, inout cache:[Int]) -> Int {
    var steps = 0
    var n = number
    // ...
    cache[number] = steps
    return steps
}
```

The expression

```
found = number < steps.count ? steps[number] > 0 : false
```

can simpler be written as

```
found = number < steps.count && steps[number] > 0
```

and I prefer `if (!found)` to `if (found == false)`. But you don't need
the `found` variable at all, as this condition can be put directly into
the `while()` expression.

So now we have

```
func collatzLength(number:Int, inout cache:[Int]) -> Int {
    var steps = 0
    var n = number

    while n >= cache.count || cache[n] == 0 {
        if n % 2 == 0 {
            n /= 2
        } else {
            n = (n * 3 + 1) / 2
            steps++
        }
        steps++
    }

    steps += cache[n]
    cache[number] = steps
    return steps
}
```

Interestingly, this is a tiny bit faster than your original version
(0.027 s instead of 0.032).

You can improve the performance a bit by taking advantage of the fact that
the caching array is filled sequentially. So (in the context of this program)

```
    while n >= cache.count || cache[n] == 0 {
```

can be replaced by

```
   while n >= number {
```

and this reduces the time to 0.016 s.

In `longestCollatzSequence()` you are using a tuple with named components
`(number:0, steps:0)` internally, but return an unnamed tuple `(Int, Int)`.
In the calling function `euler14()` the return value is assigned to
a named tuple again. I would recommend to stick to one variant, e.g.
the named tuple:

```
func longestCollatzSequence(maxNumber:Int) -> (number: Int, steps: Int) {
    var collatzSequence = (number:0, steps:0)
    var cache:[Int] = [Int](count: maxNumber, repeatedValue: 0)
    cache[1] = 1

    for var number = 2; number < maxNumber; number++ {
        let steps = collatzLength(number, &cache)
        if steps > collatzSequence.steps {
            collatzSequence = (number, steps)
        }
    }

    return collatzSequence
}
```

The for loop can equivalently  be written using a Swift range:

```
for number in 2 ..< maxNumber { ... }
```

The main function can now be simplified to

```
func euler14() {
    let result = longestCollatzSequence(999_999)
    println(result.number)
}
```

or alternatively

```
func euler14() {
    let (number, steps) = longestCollatzSequence(999_999)
    println(number)
}
```

Finally note that your `longestCollatzSequence()` function considers
all number *below* the given parameter, so you should either call

```
longestCollatzSequence(1_000_000)
```

or change the function to *include* the given upper bound.

Comment: I did not think at all about the `n >= number` condition! Really nice. Also, I did not know I could name the tuple in the return parameter. Now I do!
Thanks for the great review.

Answer (score 0):

The only optimisation I can think of is to move to Bitwise operations:

```
if number & 1 {  // Check if number is Odd
    number = (number * 3 + 1)>>1
    numberOfSteps++
} else {
    number >>=1
}
```

One more could be to run an internal for loop after the calculation is done like this:
    for var start= number; number < maxNumber; number>>1 {
        steps[start] = ++steps;
    }

So you can check this for loop if it performs better:

```
for var number = 2; number < maxNumber; number++ {

    let steps = ( steps[number] > 0)? steps[number] : collatzSequenceForNumber(number, &steps)
    if steps > collatzSequence.steps {
        collatzSequence = (number, steps)
    }
    for var start= number>>1; number < maxNumber; number>>1 {
        steps[start] = ++steps;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you try out your code ?

Comment: I haven't yet. Do let me know if you face any problem, will check and help wherever possible.

Comment: Well you cannot do this in swift : `if number & 1 {`
And the inner loop seems to make the code much more slower.

Comment: okk.. Thanks for the input. But number&1==0 can work ..right? Will check if this could be used to fasten the process.